# How big is Ego the Living Planet in his comic form?

Tags: marvel, comics

I am referring to his form in the comics, not the MCU version. I am referring to his maximum (largest) size. Which exoplanet or planet of our solar system is he comparable to in size at his largest?

Comment: Ego has appeared in multiple forms over the course of more than 50 years in the comics, ranging from planetary size, down to microscopic spores; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_the_Living_Planet. You're going to need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Ok, I’ll put it at his largest size then. I’ll edit it.

Comment: In the comics? A few square inches.

Comment: I meant in the universe depicted in said comics!

Comment: @LouisHolmes I think Ifurini was kidding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_3)*, Ego has a diameter of **4165 miles** in his "living planet" form.

That makes him slightly smaller than Mars, [which has a diameter of 4220 miles](https://mars.nasa.gov/all-about-mars/facts/).

> DIAMETER: 4165 miles
>
> MASS: Unrevealed
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #3* (July, 2008)</sub>

---

The following measurements aren't canon, but using the figure given for Ego's diameter, we can work out that he should have an approximate circumference of **13000 miles**, an approximate surface area of **54 million square miles**, and an approximate volume of **38 billion cubic miles**, rounding to two significant figures in each instance.

π × 4165 = 13084.7334022

4 × π × (4165 ÷ 2)² = 54497914.6202

(4 ÷ 3) × π × (4165 ÷ 2)³ = 37830635732.2

Comment: Volume 2. Deluxe Edition (1985) concurs, as does the Volume 3. Master Edition (1993) and the 2008 Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z